# How to apply rewrite inside a specific subexpression?

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

I'm using the online book "Software Foundations" to learn about Coq.

In the second chapter, it is asked to prove the "plus_assoc" theorem:

```
Theorem plus_assoc : forall n m p : nat, n + (m + p) = (n + m) + p.
```

I make use of two previously proven theorems:

```
Theorem plus_comm : forall n m : nat, n + m = m + n.
Theorem plus_n_Sm : forall n m : nat, S (n + m) = n + (S m).
```

I prove the plus_assoc theorem using induction on n:

```
Proof.
  intros n m p.
  induction n as [ | n' ].
    reflexivity.

    rewrite plus_comm.
    rewrite <- plus_n_Sm.
    rewrite plus_comm.
    rewrite IHn'.
    symmetry.
    rewrite plus_comm.
```

At this point, the context (*) is:

```
1 subgoals
case := "n = S n'" : String.string
n' : nat
m : nat
p : nat
IHn' : n' + (m + p) = n' + m + p
______________________________________(1/1)
p + (S n' + m) = S (n' + m + p)
```

I would like to use plus_comm to get

```
p + (m + S n') = S (n' + m + p)
```

then plus_n_sm

```
p + S (m + n') = S (n' + m + p)
```

then again plus_n_sm

```
S (p + (m + n')) = S (n' + m + p)
```

and finish the proof using plus_comm twice then reflexivity

```
S (p + (n' + m)) = S (n' + m + p)
S (n' + m + p) = S (n' + m + p)
```

The small question is that I don't know how to apply plus_comm to (S n' + m).

The great question is: why issuing

```
apply plus_comm.
```

finishes the proof instantly (in the given context (*)) ?

Thank you in advance for any clarification !

Fabian Pijcke

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply plus_comm to (S n' + m) by instantiating it with (S n') and m.

```
    Check plus_comm.
    Check plus_comm (S n').
    Check plus_comm (S n') m.
    rewrite (plus_comm (S n') m).
    rewrite <- plus_n_Sm.
    rewrite <- plus_n_Sm.
    rewrite (plus_comm m n').
    rewrite plus_comm.
    reflexivity.
Qed.
```

I think using `Require Import Coq.Setoids.Setoid.` and then using `rewrite plus_comm at 2.` is
supposed to have the same effect, but it doesn't work.

The reason `apply plus_comm` finishes the goal is because `apply` performs unification
modulo conversion. That is to say, `p + (S n' + m) = S (n' + m + p)` is convertible to
`p + (S n' + m) = S n' + m + p`, and `p + (S n' + m) = S n' + m + p` is unifiable with
`?1 + ?2 = ?2 + ?1`.

In fact, if you perform reduction using the `simpl` tactic the proof becomes shorter.

```
Theorem plus_assoc : forall n m p : nat, n + (m + p) = (n + m) + p.
Proof.
induction n.
  reflexivity.

  intros.
  simpl.
  apply f_equal.
  apply IHn.
Qed.
```

Comment: So fast, so pertinent, so complete ! This fully answers my questions, thank you very much ! This f_equal rewrite is indeed very useful.

Comment: Regarding `rewrite plus_comm at 2`, see this: https://coq.inria.fr/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=2474.